# Substituting client-side getInfo() for server side in function to pass into map() function in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, feature-collection

I am trying to clip an image over a FeatureCollection and then export each cropped image using the Python API.

```py
import ee
# Authenticate to Earth Engine
ee.Initialize()

# Load the images and feature collections
age = ee.Image('users/celsohlsj/public/secondary_vegetation_age_collection71_v5').select('classification_2020')
biomass = ee.Image('projects/ee-ana-zonia/assets/biomass_2020')
sd = ee.Image('projects/ee-ana-zonia/assets/biomass_sd_2020')
cwd = ee.Image('projects/ee-ana-zonia/assets/cwd_chave')

# Regions of interest
amazon_biome = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-ana-zonia/assets/amazon_biome_border')
indig_land = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-ana-zonia/assets/indig_land')
ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017")
ecoregions = ecoregions.filterBounds(amazon_biome.geometry())
ecoregions_list = ecoregions.toList(ecoregions.size())

# Clip to Amazon biome
age = age.clip(amazon_biome).updateMask(age.gt(0))
biomass = biomass.clip(amazon_biome)
sd = sd.clip(amazon_biome)
cwd = cwd.clip(amazon_biome)

# add and rename bands
img_export = age.addBands(biomass).addBands(sd).addBands(cwd).rename(['age', 'agbd', 'agbd_sd', 'cwd'])
# Reproject to 10m
img_export = img_export.reproject(crs=age.projection(), scale=10)
# Reaggregate to 30m (mean value)
img_export = img_export.reduceResolution(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean()).reproject(crs=age.projection())
# Mask only to regions with age greater than zero (secondary forests)
img_export = img_export.updateMask(age).float()

def export_by_ecoregion(feature):
    ecoreg = ee.Feature(feature)
    img = img_export.clip(ecoreg)
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
        image=img,
        description=f"img_export_{ecoreg.get('ECO_ID').getInfo()}",
        folder='drive_export',
        region=ecoreg.geometry(),
        crs=img.projection().getInfo()['crs'],
        crsTransform=img.projection().getInfo()['transform'],
        skipEmptyTiles = True,
        maxPixels=4e10
    )
    task.start()

ecoregions.map(export_by_ecoregion)
```

The code exports perfectly when I run then one by one, but if I try to use `.map()` I get this:

```
ee.ee_exception.EEException: A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations
```

I understand `.getInfo` is client side, is there a way I can get the same output on the server side without running the code by hand?

I also tried a for loop to iterate over a list of features made from the FeatureCollection, but that had its own issues (Unable to export unbounded image. (Error code: 3), even if "region" had been specified correctly). I had read that for loops are discouraged in GEE, I believe that may be why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `ECO_ID` property is unique for each feature, then you can do something like this:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/59f7ea67318cbc51e782bb6ef3bb2198

```py
def export_by_ecoregion(eco_id):
    ecoreg =  ecoregions.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ECO_ID",eco_id))
    img = img_export.clip(ecoreg)
    proj = img.projection().getInfo()
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
            image=img,
            description=f"img_export_{eco_id}",
            folder='drive_export',
            region=ecoreg.geometry(),
            crs=proj["crs"],
            crsTransform=proj["transform"],
            skipEmptyTiles = True,
            maxPixels=4e10
        )
    task.start()

for eco_id in ecoregions.aggregate_array("ECO_ID").getInfo():
    export_by_ecoregion(eco_id)
```

However, I would double check what you are trying to do with the reprojections, it might not be what you are expecting. Here's the projection information that you are getting:

```
{
  "type": "Projection",
  "crs": "EPSG:4326",
  "transform": [
    0.0002694945852358564,
    0,
    -73.99027736567487,
    0,
    -0.0002694945852358564,
    5.271044592628117
  ]
}
```

> Recommended reading: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection

Since it's the same value for each image, you can remove the call to `img.projection().getInfo()` and simply hard-code the crs and crsTransform that you want the exports to have.

Comment: Yeah, Oliver's solution is "the way".  Run getInfo on "something" that you can later use as an ideifntier and loop over those.  (This is the one place in EE where you actually *need* to use a for loop).  See also: https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26

Comment: Awesome, I would've never guessed, thanks a lot!

Comment: With the reprojections, I was trying to account for edge pixels. I have the age data at 30m resolution and biomass at 100m, so many "age" pixels were overlapped by multiple biomass values. I was advised to reduce the resolution to 10m, aggregate with a mean, and I'd end up with "intermediate" biomass for the edges, which turned out great as I visualized every step of the way. The weird projection is how it actually looks like for the 30m resolution "age" file. I think in this case I couldn't avoid it, but it's good to know that for the future